# How to express several whitespaces in a regex?

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

My question goes as the title says: is there any way to "tell" a regex there's a big blank between two fields of s string? With big I mean trailing whitespaces, or tabs, or any combination of both.
The thing is I'm working with strings wich I must extract some fields from. Something like:

```
label OPCODE operand
```

The regex I'm using is as follows:

```
"([a-z]*)(\\s)([A-Z]+)(\\s)([a-z]*)"
```

The problem is java only recognizes every " \s" character as just one space, and doesn't count for tabs.
If anyone can help me I'd really appreciate it! :)

Comment: What do you think `[A-Z]+` means? By the same way you can match multiple spaces too. And `\s` should match tabs by the docs

Comment: `"\\s+"` should match one or more whitespace, and tabs are definitely included.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys! The questions was a bit silly, but I was taught this just yesterday, so xD it's a bit complicated for me to completely understand it right away. Anyway, thanks again for your kind help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\s` metacharacter should account for tabs. What you're missing is the quantifier. You need a `+` or `*` quantifier (depending on whether you allow no space between the two segments) to detect any number of whitespaces.